# Sequential dataframe passing to a function

Tags: r, dataframe

Feeding a data.frame sequentially through a function call isn't updating properly?

I have attempted to create a new data.frame containing only those four columns that I need sent through the function, but it doesn't seem to work?

The following is my function call

```
library(epitools)
library(tidyverse)
midp <- function(df) {



  # Evaluates the pval of the midp function based on two proportions of a dataframe that contain both the national rate and the rate of the hospital by Number of Infections/Device Days.  

  df1 <- rateratio.midp(c(df$X1 , df$X2, df$N1, df$N2)) 


  df2 <- data.frame(df1$p.value)  
  df3 <- round(select(df2, `midp.exact`), digits = 3)  
  df4 <- data.frame(df3[(nrow(df3)/2+1):(nrow(df3)),]) 
  df4 <- rename(df4,pval =  df3..nrow.df3..2...1...nrow.df3..... )

  df <- cbind(df, df4)



}
```

My data frame

```
df <- data.frame( "X1" = c(1703, 4666, 1703, 4666), "X2" = c(0,3,0,4), "N1" = c(833658, 2758180, 833658, 2758180), "N2" = c(163, 3271, 989, 3223))
```

When I pass this df through my code, it should produce a final column in the table that contains the P-Value (pval), in order to check the code, I pass each variable through individually with the following checks

```
x <- rateratio.midp(c(df$X1[1] , df$X2[1], df$N1[1], df$N2[1]))
xx <- rateratio.midp(c(df$X1[2] , df$X2[2], df$N1[2], df$N2[2]))
```

In which case the x$p.value[2] and xx$p.value[2] should be the values (0.716, 0.284) in the pval 1 and 2 position on the df, respectively. but they are not. Instead it seems to be keeping the 1703 and 833658 values in the X1 and N1 position on the second iteration.

I expect the output of the function call originally to be 0.717, 0.284, 0.133, 0.572, but the actual output is 0.717, 0.138, 0.133, 0.321.

Comment: I would assume that you want to pass the column names instead of the values in the function

Comment: I want the function to effectively do what the x and xx are doing. The first time the function goes through I want it to use the value in position [1] then position [2] I want the values passed through the function, that particular function takes the values as an Rx2 table and uses them to compare rates to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to loop through each row, use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(epitools)
midp <- function(dat) {
      pmap(dat, ~  data.frame(rateratio.midp(c(...))$p.value)['midp.exact'] %>%
                   round(3)
                 )


    }

midp(df)
```

Comment: pmap is still returning the same output as above.

Comment: @Trevor What you showed by 'x', 'xx' is automated with `pmap`

Comment: When I applied the function as shown: 

```{r}
midp <- function(df) {
  pmap(df, ~ data.frame(rateratio.midp(c(df$X1, df$X2, df$N1, df$N2))$p.value)['midp.exact'] %>%
         round(3)
  )
  
  
}
```
it produces a table that contains the same values as the original function, the x and xx produces values that are not the same as the pmap.

x produces a pval = .717 (which is correct given the values that should be passed through)
xx produces a pval = .284 (which is correct given the values that should be passed through as well)

Comment: instead pmap produces the value of .138 in the xx or [2] position.

Comment: @Trevor I get `[[1]]
         midp.exact
Exposed1         NA
Exposed2      0.717

[[2]]
         midp.exact
Exposed1         NA
Exposed2      0.284

[[3]]
         midp.exact
Exposed1         NA
Exposed2      0.133

[[4]]
         midp.exact
Exposed1         NA
Exposed2      0.572`

Comment: You helped me figure it out! It works now, I am not sure why it was showing the wrong results for me the first time...  :( but I cleaned it and ran it again. and it worked.